# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$media_type

Tags: php, undefined

I am currently setting up my portfolio, but I keep getting the following error:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$media_type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$media_type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 59
>   1. Dot
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$media_type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 54
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$media_type in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 59

1. Circle

this is the code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (!is_numeric($id)) {
    //die('DONT BE A JERK');
    header('Location: index.php');
}

require_once('includes/config.php');
require_once('includes/lib.php');

$db = dbConnect();

$query = "
SELECT projects.* FROM projects
WHERE projects.id = '$id'
";

$project = dbSelect($db, $query);
$project = $project[0];


$query = "
    SELECT media.* FROM media
    WHERE media.project_id = '$project->id'
    ORDER BY media.rank ASC
";

$media = dbSelect($db, $query);

$project->media = $media;

dbClose($db);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Missy Skae</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1><?=$project->title;?></h1>
<h2><?=$project->date;?></h2>
<p><?=$project->description;?></p>

<?
foreach($project->media as $media) {

    ?>
    <div class="media">
```

the line after this is line 54.

```
        <?
        if ($media->media_type == 'image') {
            ?>
                <img src="media/<?=$media->filename;?>">
                <p><?=$media->imagenumber;?></p>
            <?

        } elseif ($media->media_type == 'video') {
            // video
        }
        ?>

        <p><?=$media->imagedescription;?></p>
    </div>
    <?
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what are the columns of your media table?

Comment: id, project_id, primary, rank, filename, mediatype, imagedescription, imagenumber

Answer (score 2):

Change all instances of `$media->media_type` to `$media->mediatype` to match the column in your database.  That should fix your issue.  I agree with @DanFromGermany that you should probably look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) / [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for interacting with your database.

Comment: Good spotted! I'd use `$media->{media.type}`, or set an alias in the query, or use PDO and bind the results.. many ways lead to rome :D

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that! Now I get this though....Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 55

Comment: In your file, could you do a `var_dump($media->mediatype);` and update your question with the results?  It's not clear what your `dbSelect()` function here is returning.

Comment: where do I place the var_dump?

Comment: anywhere after you make the query to the media table.  I would add a `die;` after it to stop execution so you can inspect the output.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: media in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 29

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/year_3/Site_2/portfolio/project.php on line 29
NULL

Answer (score 1):

Wrong:

```
$query = "
    SELECT media.* FROM media
    WHERE media.project_id = '$project->id'
    ORDER BY media.rank ASC
";
```

Right:

```
$query = "
    SELECT media.* FROM media
    WHERE media.project_id = '" . $project->id . "'
    ORDER BY media.rank ASC
";
```

More:

```
$project = dbSelect($db, $query);
$project = $project[0];
```

Make sure you get the correct values here.
**It seems to me, there is no result or, result returned in a different form (array).**

```
header('Location: index.php');
```

The script goes on executing if you don't use `exit;` after it.

Short open tags should not be used, they are off by default on most servers:

```
<?=$media->imagedescription;?>

<?php echo $media->imagedescription; ?>
```

Have a look into `PDO` and prepared statements. Way cleaner and easier to maintain :-)

Comment: I don't think this is OP's issue, the original query should work since it is inside of double quotes and `$project->id` should be interpolated correctly. That said, your code to me is much more readable.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but it didn't change anything. Why is the first one wrong?

Comment: @MissySkae It's not 100% reliable to work when you put variables straight into a string. But it might work tho.